# Azure Active Directory revoke a set of user-sessions for a given aad app-id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a mobile application that uses AAD authentication. We updated the privacy notice recently, and we want all our users to see the new notice.

However, the privacy notice seen check happens only during app-sign in. So we want to sign-out the users who haven't accepted the latest privacy notice of our application.

We have the list of users from to be signed out prepared from our consent db data.

Is there a REST api for AAD or a AZ-CLI command that helps us to pass-in ClientId & UPN and revoke their token.

The closest I encountered is `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken`, but I do not have permission to execute the command.

Answer (score 2):

Here either the user has manually sing off or the other only opotion is to use the PowerShell Command to revoke the user refresh token.

Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken [] or Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId   Or you can get more creative like for example revoking access for all members of a particular group

C:> Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString CloudSecGrp | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken. You need to have a Global administrator rights to execute the command

Comment: Can i restrict the Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken to a single app-id. I dont want to sign out the user from all his AAD logins (like outlook, teams etc)

Comment: I did not find a way to invalidate the refresh token to specific app-id only